# How do I pass the id value to the function?

Tags: php, jquery, html

How do I pass the id value to the function?
What I am doing is, When the user changes the dropdown then it will get the value of dropdown and also get the input value which is hidden inside foreach.

I tried from my side  I am getting on change the value from the dropdown but how do I get the input value in the jquery? now I am getting the last value of the input field.

```
 $x=1;
 foreach ($duration as $row) {?>
  <input type="hidden" name="activeID" id="activeID<?php echo $x;?>" value="<?php echo $row->activity_name_id;?>">
 <select name="Duration<?php echo $x;?>"  class="form-control" id="Duration<?php echo $x;?>">
     <option selected disabled >Select year</option>    
     <option value="12m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '12m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>1 Year</option>
     <option value="6m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '6m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>6 months</option>
  </select>
<div id="results<?php echo $x;?>"></div>

    <?php $x++;}
```

**jquery**

```
$('[id^="Duration"]').change(function () {
  var a=$('input[id^="activeID"]').attr('id');// how to I display the input id here
  alert(a);
 var value = $('input[id^="activityID"]').val();// i tried this one as well
 alert(value);
 var end = this.value;
 alert(end);//getting drodpown id value
    });
```

Comment: Try to access the element using `$(this)`

Comment: Where should I use this?

Comment: select is inside foreach ???

Comment: I recommend put the `select` and `input` in the same `div` and then when you change the dropdown, get the `siblings()`

Comment: @sradha, Yes, you can check in the question. select and input field both are inside foreach.

Comment: Replace this line `var a=$('input[id^="activeID"]').attr('id');` with `var a=$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: @Ramesh,If I try var a=$(this).attr('id'); then it's displaying only the dropdown Id not input value. I am gettng "Duration1" or "Duration2". I need input field value.

Comment: @user9437856 My bad, sorry it has to be like this: `var a=$(this).siblings('input[id^="activeID"]').attr('id');`

Comment: @Ramesh, I tried your code but it's displaying "undefined".

Comment: @user9437856 it means the way you tried to access is wrong. For the solution add a class to the `input`. Let me say the class is `active-input`. So I can access the element like `var a=$(this).siblings('.active-input').attr('id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `input` and `select` inside a `div`. When the dropdowns are changed, get the `input` sibling

```
<?php
$x=1;
foreach ($duration as $row) {
?>
  <div>
    //Your input and select here
  </div>
<?php   } ?>


<script>

$('[id^="Duration"]').change(function () {
   var input = $($(this).siblings("input")[0]); // get the input element
   var id = input.attr("id"); //id of the input
   var value = input.val(); //value of the input
   alert(value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I got a error in console after selecting the dropdown "TypeError: $(...).siblings(...)[0].val is not a functio"

Comment: It's giving me a error "TypeError: input.attr is not a function"

Comment: @user9437856: sorry my bad, the siblings()[0] return a html element, I have to parse it to jquery object. I updated my code, please try again

Comment: Oh!, Yes, Finally I got my output. @catcon, thanks for the answer and understand my issue. I just want to know about the "div". if I add one more div than what should i use in the jquery?

Comment: Why I am asking is,  there is a <div id="results<?php echo $x;?>"></div> and that is outside of the div. so how do I get id name in the jquery?

Comment: The logic would be the same, you put the `<div id="results<?php echo $x;?>">` inside the new `div` and then get the `siblings("div")[0]` of the `<select>` when it changes value

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have observed in your code:

```
$x=1;
 foreach ($duration as $row) {
  <input type="hidden" name="activeID" id="activeID<?php echo $x;?>" value="<?php echo $row->activity_name_id;?>">
 <select name="Duration<?php echo $x;?>"  class="form-control" id="Duration<?php echo $x;?>">
     <option selected disabled >Select year</option>    
     <option value="12m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '12m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>1 Year</option>
     <option value="6m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '6m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>6 months</option>
  </select>
<div id="results<?php echo $x;?>"></div>
    }
```

You are not at all increasing `$x` anywhere and hence each and every hidden input tag is getting `id = 'activeId1'`

Comment: Sure, Thanks :)

Comment: It's my fault I forgot to add in the question. I added in the question.

Comment: in the view source I am getting "activeId1" or ""activeId2" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$x=1;
 foreach ($duration as $row) {
    ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="activeID" id="activeID<?php echo $x;?>" value="<?php echo $row->activity_name_id;?>">
 <select name="Duration<?php echo $x;?>"  class="form-control DurationClass" id="Duration<?php echo $x;?>">
     <option selected disabled >Select year</option>    
     <option value="12m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '12m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>1 Year</option>
     <option value="6m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '6m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>6 months</option>
  </select>
<div id="results<?php echo $x;?>"></div>
<?php   } ?>


<script>

$('.DurationClass').change(function () {
   var a=$('input[id^="activeID"]').attr('id'); 
   var selectID=$(this).attr('id'); 
  //alert(a);
 var value = $(this).val(); //  in loop every dropdown select current option value return
 alert(value);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: If I try   var selectID=$(this).attr('id'); then it's displaying only the dropdown Id not input value.

Comment: forget this line and user var value = $(this).val();  these  return to current drop down select  value.

Comment: I don't want current drop-down select value. that I am already getting it. catcon, answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange event in your HTML part of the code

```
$x=1;
 foreach ($duration as $row) {?>
  <input type="hidden" class="activeID" name="activeID" id="activeID<?php echo $x;?>" value="<?php echo $row->activity_name_id;?>">
 <select name="Duration<?php echo $x;?>" onchange="myfunction();" class="form-control" id="Duration<?php echo $x;?>">
     <option selected disabled >Select year</option>    
     <option value="12m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '12m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>1 Year</option>
     <option value="6m" <?php if($row->Duration  == '6m' ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>6 months</option>
  </select>
<div id="results<?php echo $x;?>"></div>

    <?php $x++;}
```

Here is the function

```
function myfunction () {
  alert($(this).parent()); //what are you getting
  alert($(this).parent().find(".activeID").value()); //what are you getting?
  alert("Id of the select box is "+ this.id);
  alert("Value of the select box is "+this.value );
    };
```

Comment: I just want to know, how it will display the input field value in the alert?

Comment: @user9437856 okay I just showed above the value and id both in alert. you can remove the id part.

Comment: @user9437856 ok I got it what you are looking for try the above code and tell me what output you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".select").change(function(){
  alert("Id of the select box is "+ this.id);
  alert("Value of the select box is "+this.value );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: select</h2>
  <p>The form below contains two dropdown menus (select lists):</p>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
      <select class="form-control select" id="Sell">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
      <label for="sel1-item">Select list sell item (select one):</label>
      <select class="form-control select" id="Sell-item">
        <option>car</option>
        <option>bike</option>
        <option>cycle</option>
        <option>auto</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have to check my code again, You edited my code and remove the $x++ also you remove the PHP tags after foreach.

Comment: Also in your answer, you haven't use the input fields. I have input field inside foreach and I need that value.

Comment: I have just given the sample for jquery.

Comment: That is not my issue, but thanks for the answer, Jquery which you shared that already in my code and that it working. I need input field value in the jquery and i.e. not in your answer.